# How to sort an associate array till the specified offfset - php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, associative-array

I have an array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            ['id'] => 130
            ['point'] => 45

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
             ['id'] => 190
            ['point'] => 30
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            ['id'] => 145
            ['point'] => 79
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            ['id'] => 178
            ['point'] => 40
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            ['id'] => 189
            ['point'] => 79
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            ['id'] => 132
            ['point'] => 9
        )

)
```

I want to sort the each three elements of this array separately on `point` in descending order.

Taking the above example

I want to sort `[0],[1],[2]` of the above array and `[3],[4],[5]` separately on the `point` so the final output will be

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                ['id'] => 145
                ['point'] => 79

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                ['id'] => 130
                ['point'] => 45
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                 ['id'] => 190
                 ['point'] => 30
            )
        [3] => Array
            (
                ['id'] => 189
                ['point'] => 79
            )
        [4] => Array
            (
                 ['id'] => 178
                 ['point'] => 40
            )
        [5] => Array
            (
                ['id'] => 132
                ['point'] => 9
            )

    )
```

I have tried some codes, but I couldn't get this to work, Please help.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [usort](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

```
 usort($arr, function($e1, $e2) {
      return $e1['point'] < $e2['point'];
 });
```

Complete solution:

```
 $splits = array_chunk($arr, 3);
 $result = array();
 foreach ($splits as $split) {
    usort($split, function($e1, $e2) {
            return $e1['point'] < $e2['point'];
    });
    $result = array_merge($result, $split);
 }

 print_r($result);
```

Comment: that cannot give the solution.. please read my question and please see my required output too

Comment: This is actually a part of the process, but I've provided a more detailed answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22095397/1438393).

Comment: I thought the rest was easy, so I preferred to get coffee instead of writing it down.

Comment: Why the downvote? It returns the results exactly as requested?!

Comment: @user3357227 The edited solution returns the results exactly as requested. In the original answer I tried to help quickly with the function that presumably was unknown.

Comment: @steffen I never down voted you, That works perfectly thank you

Comment: @steffen could you give me an upvote on any of my question so that I can give upvote to you as well as Amal Murali. He has also taken effort.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it:

- Split the array into two chunks using [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/array_chunk)
- Store the arrays in two different variables
- Define a custom sorting function to use as a callback for [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort)
- Sort the two arrays using the above-defined callback function
- Join both the arrays using [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array_merge) to obtain the result array

Code:

```
// split the array into two chunks of 3
$chunks = array_chunk($data, 3);

// assign them into separate array variables
$firstArr = $chunks[0];
$secondArr = $chunks[1];

// define the sort function
function cmp($a, $b){
    return ($a['point'] > $b['point']) ? -1 : 1;
}

// sort the two arrays
usort($firstArr, 'cmp');
usort($secondArr, 'cmp');

// join them back to obtain the result
$result = array_merge($firstArr, $secondArr);

print_r($result);
```

A condensed version of the above code that will take care of multiple chunks:

```
$result = array();
foreach (array_chunk($data, 3) as $chunk) {
    usort($chunk, function($a, $b) {
        return $a['point'] < $b['point'];
    });
    $result = array_merge($result, $chunk);
}
```

[**Online demo**](https://eval.in/107616)

Comment: Thank for your quick response, but steffan's code matched my requirement perfectly so I accept his answer as the correct one , Once I get enough reputation to upvote, I will surely upvote you.

Comment: @user3357227: How does this not match your requirement "perfectly"?

Comment: Your code is also correct , But I have to edit your code for more multiple array.He gave an apt answer. And also I have accepted his answer, May be I will give you upvotes, if it matters with the points

Comment: @user3357227: I thought was obvious. And I also wanted to explain what's going on instead of dumping the code. Anyway, I've updated the answer to include the "condensed" version. Note that the other answer initially only had the `usort()` function and the rest of the code came ***after*** I had posted this answer (see [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22095350/revisions)). And the code looks very similar to mine except with a few cosmetic changes. You should always "accept" a more complete solution (one that was *most* helpful to you). Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$arr_temp1 = array();
$arr_temp2 = array();
foreach($your_array as $key=>$arr)
{
    if($key<3)
    {
        $arr_temp1[] = $arr;
    } 
    else 
    {
        $arr_temp2[] = $arr;
    }
}

usort($arr_temp1, function($a1, $a2) {
      return $a1['point'] < $a2['point'];
 });

usort($arr_temp2, function($a1, $a2) {
      return $a1['point'] > $a2['point'];
 });

$arr_new = array();
foreach($arr_temp1 as $arr)
{
   $arr_new[] = $arr;
}

foreach($arr_temp2 as $arr)
{
   $arr_new[] = $arr;
}

print_r($arr_new);
```